# User ID Clearing

Tags: google-analytics

This is not SEO related but somewhat merely client related. 
There is a website in particular that uses Google Analytics tracking to uniquely identify each one of their users. 
This website has a blocking system that is preventing me from viewing some of their content, which I'd like to view.

I figured out that the website uses the Google Analytics cookie to somehow identify me.

Is there a way I can somehow spoof the client-ID from Google Analytics to basically make a new identity for myself? Thanks community.

Answer (score 0):

GA has two ids that could identify a user, clientId and userId. The client id is set by the javascript tracking code. To delete that you would simply have to delete the _ga cookie. You will get a new ID randomly generated that does not identify you other than in the sense that multiple pageviews with that clientId will be treated as coming from the same user.

The userId is set by the server when a user logs in (to connect all sessions of that user, however it must not personally identify the user in question), so at that point the website already has to know you to set a userid.

It seems more than unlikely (and technologically not even feasible) to use Google Analytics to limit access to a website. For starters, Google provides an [opt-out plugin for Analytics](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout?hl=en) that would make such a system rather ineffectual, and I'm not quite sure how such a system would work.

To yet answer your question, you can change the clientId by manipulating the _ga cookie and replace the value therein, and you could spoof the userID e.g. by using a [browser plugin that allows you to manipulate http requests](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa). However I don't think this will let you bypass any access protection.